# browser does responsed to server.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
/* set up get all the tools we need */

var express  = require('express'),
moment   = require('moment'), 
app      = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
port     = process.env.PORT || 21017,
mongoose = require('mongoose');



// configuration connect to our database mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose*/

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

mongoose.connect(configDB.url, function(err,res){

    if(err){
       console.log('Error connecting to:' + configDB.url + '. '+ err);
    }else{
       console.log('Succeeded connecting to:' + configDB.url);
 }
}); 


app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({

extended:false

}));

app.use(require('express-promise')());  //setup inline promises

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));




//models

var reminderSchema = mongoose.Schema({

title: String,
isCompleted: Boolean,
end: { type: Date, default: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate() }
});

var Reminder = mongoose.model('Reminder', reminderSchema);

// launch

app.listen(port);

console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

when i run $node server from ubuntu 14 the logs show this:

```
The magic happens on port 21017
Succeeded connecting to:mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose
```

but when i navigate to link mongodb://localhost:21027/HelloMongoose i get

```
the address wasn't understood" by mozilla firefox.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting like this:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1/HelloMongoose
```

Comment: I highly recommend getting RoboMongo. It is great software for checking your mongodb database, it's open source and it's FREE! http://robomongo.org/